# php - Editing a profile page of a user

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm currently trying to make a profile editing page. I'm using php and MySQL for the database. I don't know much about php and MySQL. My question is: When I press submit I get a blank page. It doesn't print out the error or the success. Any thoughts on how to solve it? Here is my php code:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include_once 'dbconfig.php';
  if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $username= $userRow["user_name"];
    $useremail= $userRow["user_email"];
    $userabout= $userRow["user_about"];

    $results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET user_name='$username', user_email='$useremail', user_about='username' WHERE user_id=user");    

    if($results){
      print 'Success! record updated'; 
    } else {
      print 'Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error;
    }
  }
?>
```

And my Form code for updating the information of the user:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include_once 'dbconfig.php';

  if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
  }
  $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
  $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>

<div class="main">
  <form action="change.php" method="post">
    <div>
      <label for="uname"><a>User Name:</a></label>
      <input type="text" name="username"  value="<?php echo $userRow['user_name'];?>"/>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="email"><a>Email:</a></label>
      <input type="text" name="useremail"  value="<?php  echo $userRow['user_email'];?>"/>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="about"><a>About me:</a></label>
      <textarea name="userabout" rows="10" cols="30" value="<?php echo $userRow['user_about'];?>"/></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="submit"  value="Submit">

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you've a few issues here, mixing APIs and not quoting in the WHERE clause. and `<textarea>` does not have a `value` attribute.

Comment: what can i use instead of <textarea> ?

Comment: You don't have to replace your textarea with something else, just remove the value attribute and place your php echo <textarea>{over here}</textarea>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<textarea name="userabout" rows="10" cols="30" value="<?php echo $userRow['user_about'];?>"/></textarea>
```

use

```
<textarea name="userabout" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo $userRow['user_about'];?></textarea>
```

Also, this end is incorrect:

```
/></textarea>
```

However, the problem is this part:

```
user_id=user
```

`user` is not recognized and an error is thrown. Since PHP errors are not shown on your server, you do not see anything. But if you take a look at your logs, you will see problems about syntax errors in MySQL. You wanted to use `$_SESSION['user']` instead of `user` there.

Finally, your code is vulnerable both to SQL injection and XSS injection. Please escape your query or use PDO to [cope with SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and [prevent XSS injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) as well.

In many projects I have a `Common` class in PHP, which contains common functionalities. This is one of them:

```
public static function protectArrayAgainstXSS(&$arr) {
    $changed = false;
    foreach ($arr as $index => $a) {
        if (is_array($a)) {
            $changed = $changed || Common::protectArrayAgainstXSS($arr[$index]);
        } else if ($a !== null) {
            $changed = $changed || ($arr[$index] === strip_tags($a));
            $arr[$index] = strip_tags($a);
        }
    }
    return !$changed;
}
```

You can use this to protect your project against XSS injection by calling `Common::protectArrayAgainstXSS($_POST)`, for instance.

Comment: So insted of  $_SESSION['user'] i  just have to use user? i dont really know what you mean